# Replace a string where a numeric value occurs(1000000) should be in decimal format like(1,000,000.00)

Tags: c#

Input:

> "HRA 1000000 and TDA 120000 and other benefits"

OutPut required is:

> "HRA 1,000,000.00 and TDA 120,000.00 and other benefits"

```cs
string input = "HRA 1000000 and TDA 120000 and other benefits"; 
string[] numbers = Regex.Split(input, @"\D+");
foreach (string value in numbers)
{
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
    {
        string i = (value);                      
        i = String.Format("{0:n}", decimal.Parse(i, System.Globalization.NumberStyles.Any));
    }
}
```

Comment: What does your code output now?

Answer (score 1):

Check my [code](https://dotnetfiddle.net/j7IvWx)
I search for the numbers in string and replace its by the new format

```
string strRegex = @"(\d+)";
Regex myRegex = new Regex(strRegex, RegexOptions.None);
string strTargetString = @"HRA 1000000 and TDA 120000 and other benefits";

foreach(Match match in myRegex.Matches(strTargetString))
{
    strTargetString = strTargetString.Replace(match.Value, 
                                 string.Format("{0:n}", decimal.Parse(match.Value, System.Globalization.NumberStyles.Any)));            
}
```

Comment: Fails for value 1000000.00

Answer (score 0):

You could do this. Test the `value` if a decimal and replace it in the original string.

```
foreach (string value in numbers)
{
    decimal number = 0;
    decimal.TryParse(value, out number);
    if (number > 0)
    {
        input = input.Replace(value, string.Format("{0:N0}", number));
    }
}
```

Comment: My personal preference would be `if (decimal.TryParse(…`

Comment: `{0:C}` adds a currency symbol, which is not what OP wants

Comment: I thought it would be an currency amout, but he could format it [any way he likes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-numeric-format-strings). Then `0:N0` will do

Answer (score 0):

```cs
String.Format("{0:0,0.00}", 12345);     // "12,345.00"
```

Appears to be what you need.